# Create a Private Environment with Power Platform

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, power-platform

Hi I'm trying to setup my own environment in Power Platform.
A do have a community Environment licence, but i cannot complete all the Microsoft Learning workshops as this environment is limited in functionality.

I tried to create a practice environment at work.  However, I do not have the "Developer" option when i try to create my own environment.  I do have the "Sandbox" option as one of my types.

But these environments are by default to anyone,  unless you explicit limit them to an AD group.  I do not belong to an AD group exclusively.  Nor can i create one just for myself.

Is there a way to create an Environment that is Private.  Where only i can access it?

Erick

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the Community Plan have some limitations... And in my understanding when you use a Community Plan you get your own environment where you are the only one with access.
I share with you this documentation link where explain more deeply the details of this Power Apps Plan.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/dev-community-plan

Based on the screenshot taken from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/environments-overview#types-of-environments) I understand that you are already using a Developer environment.

[image]

Comment: ErickTreetops Any comment?